# Issues using curlpp after OSX homebrew install

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, homebrew, curlpp

I want to use curl/curlpp in my C++ project so I used the commands:

`brew install curl` and `brew install curlpp`

which had no issues. So to check that they were installed properly I called:

`curl --version` and `curlpp --version`

The first command gave a response, but the second issues the error:

`curlpp: command not found`

This is odd as if I check the directory `usr/local/Cellar` I can see that both curl and curlpp are there. On top of this when I add curl and curlpp to my linker in Eclipse project properties, I am unable to compile when I include `curlpp/cURLpp.hpp`, but `curl/curl.h` causes no issue.

If someone could help me with this that would be awesome, as I am a total noob when it comes to using foreign libraries in a C++ project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to install curl by yourself because macOS already have one.

Second, C++ libraries generally don't have executable.
So, `curlpp` doesn't exist.

Finally, if you want to external library, you have to tell compiler where the library is.
C++ library generally have a script to do that, `<library name>-config`.
In the case of curlpp, `curlpp-config` is the one.

You can pass `curlpp-config --cflags --libs` to your compiler to tell it about the library.

Comment: Thanks so much! I realized that I had to pass the command you mentioned in your last sentence in order for the libraries and includes to be placed in `/usr/local/`.

Also for anyone who has this same issue with Eclipse, I realized I need to do two things:

1. Go to **Properties->C/C++ Build->Cross G++ Compiler->Includes** and add the path to my include folder aka `/usr/local/include` for me

2. Go to **Properties->C/C++ Build->Cross G++ Linker->Libraries** and add the library `curlpp` as well as the search path `/usr/local/lib` aka where my libcurlpp.a file was located

Answer (score 1):

You can check installed package versions in Brew with these commands:

```
brew list --versions
brew cask list --versions
```